# NAND Translation Layer in u-boot

Tags: translation, layer, u-boot, flash-memory

Is it possible to access files in u-boot from NAND partition (formatted to t-fat/fat32, It's configured with Internal ECC) without ECC errors?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access files in u-boot from NAND partition
>   (formatted to t-fat/fat32, It's configured with Internal ECC) without
>   ECC errors?

Yes it's possible to access the file which is flat32 format.
Uboot support several file system include fat32, ext2, ext3, ext4 and Cramfs.

**Example command:**

To view the contents of a FAT32 partition the user would use

```
fatls scsi <dev>:<partition>
```

Below command list the contents of SCSI device(your device) 0 partition 1 on AM57x General Purpose EVM:

```
=> fatls scsi 0:1
   110578   test
1 file(s), 0 dir(s)
Write File to Partition
```